Avoid OrientationEventListener Callbacks when orientation changes on button click
I have an OrientationEventListener in the onCreate of my activity that does an action if the user rotates his mobile. I also have a button that if clicked, rotates the screen layout without the user's manual rotation.
The problem is that when I click the button the OrientationEventListener inside the onCreate is being activated too because the activity starts again when the screen rotates, resetting the boolean used to maintain the button click record.
What I need is for orientationEventListener callback actions to happen only if the mobile itself is rotated, not by click.
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val button = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.button)
        button.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(v: View) {
                //call function that rotates the screen for example:
                  setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            }
        })

        val sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("string", MODE_PRIVATE)
        val orientationListener: OrientationEventListener = object : OrientationEventListener(
            applicationContext
        ) {
            override fun onOrientationChanged(orientation: Int) {
                   //call function that needs to work only if the user rotates the phone without clicking the button
            }
        }
        if (orientationListener.canDetectOrientation()) {
            orientationListener.enable();
        }

    }

I tried using a boolean to indicate if the button is clicked or not, but the activity is being destroyed and starting again everytime a rotation occurs no matter if it's manual or by click, so the boolean is reseted and the onCreate/OrientationEventListener are called. Any suggestions?
P.S.: the OrientationEventListener isn't exactly the focus of this question, it's the action inside it that I need to happen when a rotation of the mobile is identified. So if you have another way to do that I'd like to hear too. The activity starting again after a rotation isn't something I need too, but it happens everytime a rotation occurs and I don't know if it's possible to stop that.

You can add following config to your manifest file to stop the activity from being re-created when a config change such as screen rotation happens.
Add the following to the  tag for your MainActivity in your manifest file:
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

This will prevent the activity from being re-created on orientation change.
Next: In your MainActivity, override the onConfigurationChanged() method to handle orientation changes without activity recreation:
override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
        isButtonClicked = false // Reset flag after handling programmatic rotation
        // Handle orientation changes here, e.g., update layout if needed
    }

This is where you can reset the isButtonClicked boolean to know if the screen orientation changed due to button click or manual rotation.
and finally in your onCreate() method you can set the isButtonClicked boolean to tru before triggering the orientation change and check it's value inside the listener to skip running code that should only run when manual rotation happens.
val button = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.button)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            isButtonClicked = true
            // Call function that rotates the screen, e.g.,
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        }

        val orientationListener = object : OrientationEventListener(this) {
            override fun onOrientationChanged(orientation: Int) {
                if (!isButtonClicked) {
                    // Call function that needs to work only for manual rotation
                    // ... your action here ...
                }
            }
        }

EDITED:
This is the complete code that goes inside your MainActivity to rotate the screen with a button click and preserve the state of the boolean.
Since we have disabled the activity re-creation when orientation changes happen due to device rotation we have to make use of orientationChangeListener to set the orientation of device rotation to respective state.
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private var isButtonClicked = false

    @SuppressLint("SwitchIntDef", "SourceLockedOrientationActivity")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.d("TAG", "Inside onCreate!")
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
        val btnRotateScreen = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_rotate_screen)

        btnRotateScreen.setOnClickListener {
            isButtonClicked = true
            Log.d("TAG", "current orientation: ${resources.configuration.orientation}")
            when (resources.configuration.orientation) {
                ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT,
                Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT -> {
                    requestedOrientation =
                        ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE
                }

                Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE,
                ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE,
                ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE -> {
                    requestedOrientation =
                        ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT
                }
            }
        }

        val orientationListener = object : OrientationEventListener(this) {
            override fun onOrientationChanged(orientation: Int) {
                Log.d("TAG", "Inside onOrientationChanged: orientation int val: $orientation")
                var isUpdated = false
                when (orientation) {
                    in 0..10,
                    in 350..360,
                    in 170..190 -> {
                        requestedOrientation =
                            ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT
                        isUpdated = true
                    }

                    in 80..100,
                    in 260..280 -> {
                        requestedOrientation =
                            ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE
                        isUpdated = true
                    }
                }
                if (isUpdated) {
                    // Do Task that needs to be done when orientation changes happens due to
                    // device rotation not button click.
                    Log.d("TAG", "Orientation changed by rotation, set button clicked to false")
                    isButtonClicked = false
                }
            }
        }

        if (orientationListener.canDetectOrientation()) {
            orientationListener.enable();
        }
    }

    override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
        Log.d(
            "TAG",
            "inside onConfiguration changed, newConfig orientation: ${newConfig.orientation}"
        )
    }
}

Feel free to leave a comment if you need more clarification.

The problem with this solution is that if the screen rotation is done by click and the person rotates it's mobile later the screen is keeping locked because of the rotation that was set by click, so the onConfigurationChanged is never called in this case because there's no actual configuration change. Also even if there wasn't that problem nothing inside the if (!isButtonClicked) would happen because the orientationListener is in the onCreate and it is called before the onConfigurationChange, so that variable would still be true at that moment.

This solution focuses on letting you maintain the boolean for user-clicked orientation changes, as you asked in your question. By adding the config-changes tag in the manifest file, you should be able to achieve that. The rest totally depends on your core logic and what you want to do with different flows on orientation changes. I've updated my code with complete MainActivity code that rotates the screen on button click as well as device rotation.

Point to remember is that when you set the orientation through code to portrait or landscape, it gets fixed to that specific orientation irrespective of device rotation, that's why onConfigurationChanged won't be called and you might have to do the configuration change inside the onOrientationListener as well.
